# Xamarin Studio lost intellisense after update , how to fix it?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

yesterday I made an update to XS on my mac but then I lost the Intellisense and the syntax check ability. Maybe it worths to mention that I have mfractor installed as an add-in .

Comment: Hi @BraveHeart, I'm really sorry that MFractor is causing this. I'm looking into it immediately.

Comment: @matthewrdev just the day I received an invatation for the training :)

Comment: I know! What a frustrating coincidence :/ A hotfix is almost ready, I'll let you know when I've deployed it.

Comment: Hello there any updates ? I think i got a new update which partially fixed it but it is not so stable

Comment: try installing version 2.9.2: http://addins.mfractor.com/releases/2.09.02/MFractor.MFractor_2.09.02.mpack

Comment: (I lost access to my main accounts for a few days, apologies for not following up sooner)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem it was because of MFractor,  once I disabled it it works as it should